# node.js app: throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.')

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code:

```
router.get('/:widget', function(req, res, next) {
        var widget = req.params.widget;
        if ( ! validate(widget) ) {
                res.status(400).send("Invalid widget");
                return;
        }

        redis.hget("e:" + widget, 'ccid', function (e, d) {
                if (e){
                        res.status(500).send("Database query failed");
                        return;
                }
                if (d) {
                        res.status(200).send("Resource found");
                        return;
                } else {
                        res.status(400).send("Unknown widget");
                        return;
                }
        });

        res.status(200).send("why are you here?");
        return;
});
```

I was under the impression that when the code hits a "return"... it exits the function. 
But what seems to be happening is that when the logic hits the:

```
  res.status(400).send("Unknown widget");
  return;
```

path, it still hits the

```
        res.status(200).send("why are you here?");
        return;
```

as well.  I thought it would have exited the method. 
Clearly, I'm wrong...  because I'm getting the above error message.  The error goes away when I remove the res.send() and return() after the redis.hget call.

What should I be using instead of the "return" statement after each res.status().send()?

Comment: Hitting a `return` _does_ exit the function. But in your case it exits the _callback_ you pass to `.hget`, you're still inside `.get('/:widget' ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"redis.hget" is an asynchronous call. As "redis.hget" is an asynchronous call, your "router.get" function keeps on executing to the end, where it encounters "res.status(200).send("why are you here?")" and hence send the response to client.

Now, in the next event loop the asynchronous function "redis.hget" gets executed which after getting the response from Redis sever, again call "res.status(400).send...". But as the response was already sent to client before, so you get the error "Can't set headers after they are sent"

Answer (score 1):

`function (e, d) { ... }` is a **different** function that is called asynchronously.

Returning from `function(req, res, next) { ... }` won't stop that function from running (or vice versa).

Given that you *always* send a response from inside `function (e, d) { ... }` , it doesn't make sense to try to send one from `function(req, res, next) { ... }` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement is in a callback function (the one you pass to `redis.hget()`). Your return statements take you out of that, but then you continue on to the end of the `router.get()` function.